# Java Graphics2D Path2D Simplify or call from separate class

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, path-2d

I'm wondering if I can clean up my code somehow using a list or call it from another class because I have a lot of exact Path2D coordinates just cluttering my paintComponent.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{ Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
super.paintComponent(g2);

//Background
Rectangle background = new Rectangle(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
Color skyBlue = new Color(135,206,235);
g2.setColor(skyBlue);
g2.fill (background);

Path2D bunny = new Path2D.Float();
bunny.moveTo(486.63,530.25);
bunny.lineTo(483.13,532.25);
bunny.lineTo(483.13,532.25);
bunny.lineTo(483.13,532.25);
bunny.lineTo(477.38,534.38);
bunny.lineTo(477.38,534.38);
bunny.lineTo(477.38,534.38);
bunny.lineTo(469.88,535.50);
bunny.lineTo(469.88,535.50);
bunny.lineTo(469.88,535.50);
bunny.lineTo(453.50,536.38);
bunny.lineTo(453.50,536.38);
bunny.lineTo(453.50,536.38);
bunny.lineTo(437.63,537.75);
bunny.lineTo(437.63,537.75);
bunny.lineTo(437.63,537.75);
bunny.lineTo(418.75,539.25);
bunny.lineTo(418.75,539.25);
bunny.lineTo(418.75,539.25);
bunny.lineTo(405.00,539.88);
bunny.lineTo(405.00,539.88);
bunny.lineTo(405.00,539.88);
bunny.lineTo(392.25,539.63);
bunny.lineTo(392.25,539.63);
bunny.lineTo(392.25,539.63);
bunny.lineTo(385.50,539.13);
bunny.lineTo(385.50,539.13);
bunny.lineTo(385.50,539.13);
bunny.lineTo(381.00,538.63);
bunny.lineTo(381.00,538.63);
bunny.lineTo(381.00,538.63);
bunny.lineTo(375.50,537.88);
bunny.lineTo(375.50,537.88);
bunny.lineTo(375.50,537.88);
bunny.lineTo(370.13,537.75);
bunny.lineTo(370.13,537.75);
bunny.lineTo(370.13,537.75);
bunny.lineTo(364.88,537.13);
bunny.lineTo(364.88,537.13);
bunny.lineTo(364.88,537.13);
bunny.lineTo(357.75,536.63);
bunny.lineTo(357.75,536.63);
bunny.lineTo(357.75,536.63);
bunny.lineTo(353.50,536.25);
bunny.lineTo(353.50,536.25);
bunny.lineTo(353.50,536.25);
bunny.lineTo(347.88,535.75);
bunny.lineTo(347.88,535.75);
bunny.lineTo(347.88,535.75);
bunny.lineTo(341.75,535.38);
bunny.lineTo(341.75,535.38);
bunny.lineTo(341.75,535.38);
bunny.lineTo(336.25,534.38);
bunny.lineTo(336.25,534.38);
bunny.lineTo(336.25,534.38);
bunny.lineTo(328.25,532.88);
bunny.lineTo(328.25,532.88);
bunny.lineTo(328.25,532.88);
bunny.lineTo(323.00,530.63);
bunny.lineTo(323.00,530.63);
bunny.lineTo(323.00,530.63);
bunny.lineTo(318.50,528.13);
bunny.lineTo(318.50,528.13);
bunny.lineTo(318.50,528.13);
bunny.lineTo(313.50,524.63);
bunny.lineTo(313.50,524.63);
bunny.lineTo(313.50,524.63);
bunny.lineTo(311.63,521.25);
bunny.lineTo(311.63,521.25);
bunny.lineTo(311.63,521.25);
bunny.lineTo(310.38,516.25);
bunny.lineTo(310.38,516.25);
bunny.lineTo(310.38,516.25);
bunny.lineTo(309.88,513.00);
bunny.lineTo(309.88,513.00);
bunny.lineTo(309.88,513.00);
bunny.lineTo(311.13,508.38);
bunny.lineTo(311.13,508.38);
bunny.lineTo(311.13,508.38);
bunny.lineTo(312.25,505.38);
bunny.lineTo(312.25,505.38);
bunny.lineTo(312.25,505.38);
bunny.lineTo(313.00,502.63);
bunny.lineTo(313.00,502.63);
bunny.lineTo(313.00,502.63);
bunny.lineTo(314.75,500.00);
bunny.lineTo(314.75,500.00);
bunny.lineTo(314.75,500.00);
bunny.lineTo(316.38,497.63);
bunny.lineTo(316.38,497.63);
bunny.lineTo(316.38,497.63);
bunny.lineTo(316.25,494.00);
bunny.lineTo(316.25,494.00);    
bunny.lineTo(316.25,494.00);
bunny.lineTo(314.88,491.00);
bunny.lineTo(314.88,491.00);
bunny.lineTo(314.88,491.00);
bunny.lineTo(312.88,486.38);
bunny.lineTo(312.88,486.38);
bunny.lineTo(312.88,486.38);
bunny.lineTo(310.13,480.00);
bunny.lineTo(310.13,480.00);
bunny.lineTo(310.13,480.00);
bunny.lineTo(308.50,474.75);
bunny.lineTo(308.50,474.75);
bunny.lineTo(308.50,474.75);
bunny.lineTo(306.63,468.75);
bunny.lineTo(306.63,468.75);
bunny.lineTo(306.63,468.75);
bunny.lineTo(305.25,462.75);
bunny.lineTo(305.25,462.75);
bunny.lineTo(305.25,462.75);
bunny.lineTo(304.88,456.63);
bunny.lineTo(304.88,456.63);
bunny.lineTo(304.88,456.63);
bunny.lineTo(304.88,449.88);
bunny.lineTo(304.88,449.88);
bunny.lineTo(304.88,449.88);
bunny.lineTo(305.00,446.38);
bunny.lineTo(305.00,446.38);
bunny.lineTo(305.00,446.38);
bunny.lineTo(305.88,442.75);
bunny.lineTo(305.88,442.75);
bunny.lineTo(305.88,442.75);
bunny.lineTo(307.63,437.88);
bunny.lineTo(307.63,437.88);
bunny.lineTo(307.63,437.88);
bunny.lineTo(309.25,434.50);
bunny.lineTo(309.25,434.50);
bunny.lineTo(309.25,434.50);
bunny.lineTo(310.50,432.25);
bunny.lineTo(310.50,432.25);
bunny.lineTo(310.50,432.25);    
bunny.lineTo(311.63,430.25);
bunny.lineTo(311.63,430.25);
bunny.lineTo(311.63,430.25);
bunny.lineTo(312.50,427.25);
bunny.lineTo(312.50,427.25);
bunny.lineTo(312.50,427.25);
bunny.lineTo(312.63,424.00);
bunny.lineTo(312.63,424.00);
bunny.lineTo(312.63,424.00);
bunny.lineTo(311.75,421.25);
bunny.lineTo(311.75,421.25);
bunny.lineTo(311.75,421.25);
bunny.lineTo(309.38,417.88);
bunny.lineTo(309.38,417.88);
bunny.lineTo(309.38,417.88);
bunny.lineTo(307.00,415.00);
bunny.lineTo(307.00,415.00);
bunny.lineTo(307.00,415.00);
bunny.lineTo(304.50,412.25);
bunny.lineTo(304.50,412.25);
bunny.lineTo(304.50,412.25);
bunny.lineTo(302.63,409.38);
bunny.lineTo(302.63,409.38);
bunny.lineTo(302.63,409.38);
bunny.lineTo(300.13,406.63);
bunny.lineTo(300.13,406.63);
bunny.lineTo(300.13,406.63);
bunny.lineTo(298.00,402.88);
bunny.lineTo(298.00,402.88);
bunny.lineTo(298.00,402.88);
bunny.lineTo(296.63,400.50);
bunny.lineTo(296.63,400.50);
bunny.lineTo(296.63,400.50);
bunny.lineTo(295.38,397.88);
bunny.lineTo(295.38,397.88);
bunny.lineTo(295.38,397.88);
bunny.lineTo(294.50,395.63);
bunny.lineTo(294.50,395.63);
bunny.lineTo(294.50,395.63);
bunny.lineTo(294.13,392.88);
bunny.lineTo(294.13,392.88);
bunny.lineTo(294.13,392.88);
bunny.lineTo(293.13,389.88);
bunny.lineTo(293.13,389.88);
bunny.lineTo(293.13,389.88);
bunny.lineTo(292.38,385.75);
bunny.lineTo(292.38,385.75);
bunny.lineTo(292.38,385.75);
bunny.lineTo(291.75,381.13);
bunny.lineTo(291.75,381.13);
bunny.lineTo(291.75,381.13);
bunny.lineTo(290.88,371.75);
bunny.lineTo(290.88,371.75);
bunny.lineTo(290.88,371.75);
bunny.lineTo(291.13,366.88);
bunny.lineTo(291.13,366.88);
bunny.lineTo(291.13,366.88);
bunny.lineTo(293.25,362.50);
bunny.lineTo(293.25,362.50);
bunny.lineTo(293.25,362.50);
bunny.lineTo(295.38,358.88);
bunny.lineTo(295.38,358.88);
bunny.lineTo(295.38,358.88);
bunny.lineTo(296.75,356.38);
bunny.lineTo(296.75,356.38);
bunny.lineTo(296.75,356.38);
bunny.lineTo(300.00,350.00);
bunny.lineTo(300.00,350.00);
bunny.lineTo(300.00,350.00);
bunny.lineTo(305.63,342.75);
bunny.lineTo(305.63,342.75);
bunny.lineTo(305.63,342.75);
bunny.lineTo(309.88,337.00);
bunny.lineTo(309.88,337.00);
bunny.lineTo(309.88,337.00);
bunny.lineTo(313.50,333.13);
bunny.lineTo(313.50,333.13);
bunny.lineTo(313.50,333.13);
bunny.lineTo(319.25,327.63);
bunny.lineTo(319.25,327.63);
bunny.lineTo(319.25,327.63);
bunny.lineTo(323.38,324.00);
bunny.lineTo(323.38,324.00);
bunny.lineTo(323.38,324.00);
bunny.lineTo(328.38,321.25);
bunny.lineTo(328.38,321.25);
bunny.lineTo(328.38,321.25);
bunny.lineTo(333.75,318.88);
bunny.lineTo(333.75,318.88);
bunny.lineTo(333.75,318.88);
bunny.lineTo(338.50,316.38);
bunny.lineTo(338.50,316.38);
bunny.lineTo(338.50,316.38);
bunny.lineTo(341.63,315.50);
bunny.lineTo(341.63,315.50);
bunny.lineTo(341.63,315.50);
bunny.lineTo(348.50,313.25);
bunny.lineTo(348.50,313.25);
bunny.lineTo(348.50,313.25);
bunny.lineTo(355.25,312.00);
bunny.lineTo(355.25,312.00);
bunny.lineTo(355.25,312.00);
bunny.lineTo(361.00,310.88);
bunny.lineTo(361.00,310.88);
bunny.lineTo(361.00,310.88);
bunny.lineTo(364.50,309.75);
bunny.lineTo(364.50,309.75);
bunny.lineTo(364.50,309.75);
bunny.lineTo(367.75,307.50);
bunny.lineTo(367.75,307.50);
bunny.lineTo(367.75,307.50);
bunny.lineTo(373.25,302.50);
bunny.lineTo(373.25,302.50);
bunny.lineTo(373.25,302.50);
bunny.lineTo(379.13,296.13);
bunny.lineTo(379.13,296.13);
bunny.lineTo(379.13,296.13);
bunny.lineTo(384.25,290.13);
bunny.lineTo(384.25,290.13);
bunny.lineTo(384.25,290.13);
bunny.lineTo(389.25,283.88);
bunny.lineTo(389.25,283.88);
bunny.lineTo(389.25,283.88);
bunny.lineTo(393.25,279.50);
bunny.lineTo(393.25,279.50);
bunny.lineTo(393.25,279.50);
bunny.lineTo(396.63,275.50);
bunny.lineTo(396.63,275.50);
bunny.lineTo(396.63,275.50);
bunny.lineTo(400.50,271.38);
bunny.lineTo(400.50,271.38);
bunny.lineTo(400.50,271.38);
bunny.lineTo(406.25,266.75);
bunny.lineTo(406.25,266.75);
bunny.lineTo(406.25,266.75);
bunny.lineTo(411.50,262.13);
bunny.lineTo(411.50,262.13);
bunny.lineTo(411.50,262.13);
bunny.lineTo(414.88,259.75);
bunny.lineTo(414.88,259.75);
bunny.lineTo(414.88,259.75);
bunny.lineTo(420.25,256.63);
bunny.lineTo(420.25,256.63);
bunny.lineTo(420.25,256.63);
bunny.lineTo(424.63,253.88);
bunny.lineTo(424.63,253.88);
bunny.lineTo(424.63,253.88);
bunny.lineTo(427.50,252.88);
bunny.lineTo(427.50,252.88);
bunny.lineTo(427.50,252.88);
bunny.lineTo(431.13,251.50);
bunny.lineTo(431.13,251.50);
bunny.lineTo(431.13,251.50);
bunny.lineTo(434.25,251.13);
bunny.lineTo(434.25,251.13);
bunny.lineTo(434.25,251.13);
bunny.lineTo(437.63,251.00);
bunny.lineTo(437.63,251.00);
bunny.lineTo(437.63,251.00);
bunny.lineTo(442.50,252.25);
bunny.lineTo(442.50,252.25);
bunny.lineTo(442.50,252.25);
bunny.lineTo(445.50,253.75);
bunny.lineTo(445.50,253.75);
bunny.lineTo(445.50,253.75);
bunny.lineTo(447.88,255.25);
bunny.lineTo(447.88,255.25);
bunny.lineTo(447.88,255.25);
bunny.lineTo(450.50,258.25);
bunny.lineTo(450.50,258.25);
bunny.lineTo(450.50,258.25);
bunny.lineTo(451.88,260.75);
bunny.lineTo(451.88,260.75);
bunny.lineTo(451.88,260.75);
bunny.lineTo(453.38,264.13);
bunny.lineTo(453.38,264.13);
bunny.lineTo(453.38,264.13);
bunny.lineTo(454.25,266.88);
bunny.lineTo(454.25,266.88);
bunny.lineTo(454.25,266.88);
bunny.lineTo(455.50,271.13);
bunny.lineTo(455.50,271.13);
bunny.lineTo(455.50,271.13);
bunny.lineTo(455.63,274.75);
bunny.lineTo(455.63,274.75);
bunny.lineTo(455.63,274.75);
bunny.lineTo(456.75,276.50);
bunny.lineTo(456.75,276.50);
bunny.lineTo(456.75,276.50);
bunny.lineTo(458.63,278.00);
bunny.lineTo(458.63,278.00);
bunny.lineTo(458.63,278.00);
bunny.lineTo(460.00,278.88);
bunny.lineTo(460.00,278.88);
bunny.lineTo(460.00,278.88);
bunny.lineTo(461.00,280.75);
bunny.lineTo(461.00,280.75);
bunny.lineTo(461.00,280.75);
bunny.lineTo(462.75,281.00);
bunny.lineTo(462.75,281.00);
bunny.lineTo(462.75,281.00);
bunny.lineTo(464.88,281.88);
bunny.lineTo(464.88,281.88);
bunny.lineTo(464.88,281.88);
bunny.lineTo(467.38,283.00);
bunny.lineTo(467.38,283.00);
bunny.lineTo(467.38,283.00);
bunny.lineTo(470.13,284.50);
bunny.lineTo(470.13,284.50);
bunny.lineTo(470.13,284.50);
bunny.lineTo(472.00,286.13);
bunny.lineTo(472.00,286.13);
bunny.lineTo(473.63,287.50);
bunny.lineTo(477.13,290.13);
bunny.lineTo(477.13,290.13);
bunny.lineTo(477.13,290.13);
bunny.lineTo(479.50,292.25);
bunny.lineTo(479.50,292.25);
bunny.lineTo(479.50,292.25);
bunny.lineTo(481.50,295.00);
bunny.lineTo(481.50,295.00);
bunny.lineTo(481.50,295.00);
bunny.lineTo(483.38,299.13);
bunny.lineTo(483.38,299.13);
bunny.lineTo(483.38,299.13);
bunny.lineTo(483.38,303.63);
bunny.lineTo(483.38,303.63);
bunny.lineTo(483.38,303.63);
bunny.lineTo(482.63,308.00);
bunny.lineTo(482.63,308.00);
bunny.lineTo(482.63,308.00);
bunny.lineTo(480.75,311.75);
bunny.lineTo(480.75,311.75);
bunny.lineTo(480.75,311.75);
bunny.lineTo(469.25,325.00);
bunny.lineTo(469.25,325.00);
bunny.lineTo(469.25,325.00);
bunny.lineTo(464.00,330.63);
bunny.lineTo(464.00,330.63);
bunny.lineTo(464.00,330.63);
bunny.lineTo(458.50,337.13);
bunny.lineTo(458.50,337.13);
bunny.lineTo(458.50,337.13);
bunny.lineTo(451.75,345.13);
bunny.lineTo(451.75,345.13);
bunny.lineTo(451.75,345.13);
bunny.lineTo(448.38,349.63);
bunny.lineTo(448.38,349.63);
bunny.lineTo(448.38,349.63);
bunny.lineTo(446.00,353.13);
bunny.lineTo(446.00,353.13);
bunny.lineTo(446.00,353.13);
bunny.lineTo(443.38,357.75);
bunny.lineTo(443.38,357.75);
bunny.lineTo(443.38,357.75);
bunny.lineTo(442.13,361.13);
bunny.lineTo(442.13,361.13);
bunny.lineTo(442.13,361.13);
bunny.lineTo(441.88,367.38);
bunny.lineTo(441.88,367.38);
bunny.lineTo(441.88,367.38);
bunny.lineTo(441.75,371.75);
bunny.lineTo(441.75,371.75);
bunny.lineTo(441.75,371.75);
bunny.lineTo(442.13,375.63);
bunny.lineTo(442.13,375.63);
bunny.lineTo(442.13,375.63);
bunny.lineTo(443.00,381.88);
bunny.lineTo(443.00,381.88);
bunny.lineTo(443.00,381.88);
bunny.lineTo(444.38,385.75);
bunny.lineTo(444.38,385.75);
bunny.lineTo(444.38,385.75);
bunny.lineTo(446.50,390.75);
bunny.lineTo(446.50,390.75);
bunny.lineTo(446.50,390.75);
bunny.lineTo(450.00,396.38);
bunny.lineTo(450.00,396.38);
bunny.lineTo(450.00,396.38);
bunny.lineTo(452.88,399.50);
bunny.lineTo(452.88,399.50);
bunny.lineTo(452.88,399.50);
bunny.lineTo(457.25,404.25);
bunny.lineTo(457.25,404.25);
bunny.lineTo(457.25,404.25);
bunny.lineTo(462.38,409.50);
bunny.lineTo(462.38,409.50);
bunny.lineTo(462.38,409.50);
bunny.lineTo(467.25,414.50);
bunny.lineTo(467.25,414.50);
bunny.lineTo(467.25,414.50);
bunny.lineTo(471.25,418.63);
bunny.lineTo(471.25,418.63);
bunny.lineTo(471.25,418.63);
bunny.lineTo(473.25,421.38);
bunny.lineTo(473.25,421.38);
bunny.lineTo(473.25,421.38);
bunny.lineTo(476.63,426.13);
bunny.lineTo(476.63,426.13);
bunny.lineTo(476.63,426.13);
bunny.lineTo(480.75,431.13);
bunny.lineTo(480.75,431.13);
bunny.lineTo(480.75,431.13);
bunny.lineTo(483.50,435.13);
bunny.lineTo(483.50,435.13);
bunny.lineTo(483.50,435.13);
bunny.lineTo(485.25,439.63);
bunny.lineTo(485.25,439.63);
bunny.lineTo(485.25,439.63);
bunny.lineTo(487.50,444.75);
bunny.lineTo(487.50,444.75);
bunny.lineTo(487.50,444.75);
bunny.lineTo(489.13,448.88);
bunny.lineTo(489.13,448.88);
bunny.lineTo(489.13,448.88);
bunny.lineTo(489.75,453.88);
bunny.lineTo(489.75,453.88);
bunny.lineTo(489.75,453.88);
bunny.lineTo(490.63,459.38);
bunny.lineTo(490.63,459.38);
bunny.lineTo(490.63,459.38);
bunny.lineTo(492.38,466.25);
bunny.lineTo(492.38,466.25);
bunny.lineTo(492.38,466.25);
bunny.lineTo(493.38,472.88);
bunny.lineTo(493.38,472.88);
bunny.lineTo(493.38,472.88);
bunny.lineTo(493.88,477.13);
bunny.lineTo(493.88,477.13);
bunny.lineTo(493.88,477.13);
bunny.lineTo(494.38,480.63);
bunny.lineTo(494.38,480.63);
bunny.lineTo(494.38,480.63);
bunny.lineTo(495.50,483.38);
bunny.lineTo(495.50,483.38);
bunny.lineTo(495.50,483.38);
bunny.lineTo(498.00,485.25);
bunny.lineTo(498.00,485.25);
bunny.lineTo(498.00,485.25);
bunny.lineTo(499.50,488.00);
bunny.lineTo(499.50,488.00);
bunny.lineTo(499.50,488.00);
bunny.lineTo(500.63,491.50);
bunny.lineTo(500.63,491.50);
bunny.lineTo(500.63,491.50);
bunny.lineTo(501.25,497.13);
bunny.lineTo(501.25,497.13);
bunny.lineTo(501.25,497.13);
bunny.lineTo(500.13,501.13);
bunny.lineTo(500.13,501.13);
bunny.lineTo(500.13,501.13);
bunny.lineTo(499.13,505.63);
bunny.lineTo(499.13,505.63);
bunny.lineTo(499.13,505.63);
bunny.lineTo(497.88,507.88);
bunny.lineTo(497.88,507.88);
bunny.lineTo(497.88,507.88);
bunny.lineTo(495.88,512.25);
bunny.lineTo(495.88,512.25);
bunny.lineTo(495.88,512.25);
bunny.lineTo(494.38,516.25);
bunny.lineTo(494.38,516.25);
bunny.lineTo(494.38,516.25);
bunny.lineTo(493.25,518.63);
bunny.lineTo(493.25,518.63);
bunny.lineTo(493.25,518.63);
bunny.lineTo(491.88,521.88);
bunny.lineTo(491.88,521.88);
bunny.lineTo(491.88,521.88);
bunny.lineTo(489.38,524.00);
bunny.lineTo(489.38,524.00);
bunny.lineTo(489.38,524.00);
bunny.lineTo(489.13,526.63);
bunny.lineTo(489.13,526.63);
bunny.lineTo(489.13,526.63);
bunny.lineTo(488.13,528.75);
bunny.lineTo(488.13,528.75);
bunny.closePath();
g2.draw(bunny);
Color gold = new Color(255,215,0);
g2.setColor(gold);
g2.fill(bunny);

Path2D chocoears = new Path2D.Float();
chocoears.moveTo(473.63, 287.50);
chocoears.lineTo(473.63,287.50);
chocoears.lineTo(477.13,290.13);
chocoears.lineTo(477.13,290.13);
chocoears.lineTo(477.13,290.13);
chocoears.lineTo(479.50,292.25);
chocoears.lineTo(479.50,292.25);
chocoears.lineTo(479.50,292.25);
chocoears.lineTo(481.50,295.00);
chocoears.lineTo(481.50,295.00);
chocoears.lineTo(481.50,295.00);
chocoears.lineTo(483.38,299.13);
chocoears.lineTo(483.38,299.13);
chocoears.lineTo(483.38,299.13);
chocoears.lineTo(483.38,303.63);
chocoears.lineTo(483.38,303.63);
chocoears.lineTo(483.38,303.63);
chocoears.lineTo(482.63,308.00);
chocoears.lineTo(482.63,308.00);
chocoears.lineTo(482.63,308.00);
chocoears.lineTo(480.75,311.75);
chocoears.lineTo(480.75,311.75);
chocoears.lineTo(480.75,311.75);
chocoears.lineTo(469.25,325.00);
chocoears.lineTo(469.25,325.00);
chocoears.lineTo(469.25,325.00);
chocoears.lineTo(464.00,330.63);
chocoears.lineTo(464.00,330.63);
chocoears.lineTo(464.00,330.63);
chocoears.lineTo(458.50,337.13);
chocoears.lineTo(458.50,337.13);
chocoears.lineTo(458.50,337.13);
chocoears.lineTo(451.75,345.13);
chocoears.lineTo(451.75,345.13);
chocoears.lineTo(451.75,345.13);
chocoears.lineTo(442.33,351.00);
chocoears.lineTo(442.33,351.00);
chocoears.lineTo(442.33,351.00);
chocoears.lineTo(435.33,351.00);
chocoears.lineTo(435.33,351.00);
chocoears.lineTo(435.33,351.00);
chocoears.lineTo(432.00,349.00);
chocoears.lineTo(432.00,349.00);
chocoears.lineTo(432.00,349.00);
chocoears.lineTo(427.00,348.67);
chocoears.lineTo(427.00,348.67);
chocoears.lineTo(427.00,348.67);
chocoears.lineTo(420.00,342.67);
chocoears.lineTo(420.00,342.67);
chocoears.lineTo(420.00,342.67);
chocoears.lineTo(415.33,339.33);
chocoears.lineTo(415.33,339.33);
chocoears.lineTo(415.33,339.33);
chocoears.lineTo(412.00,341.00);
chocoears.lineTo(412.00,341.00);
chocoears.lineTo(412.00,341.00);
chocoears.lineTo(408.33,337.00);
chocoears.lineTo(408.33,337.00);
chocoears.lineTo(408.33,337.00);
chocoears.lineTo(407.33,333.33);
chocoears.lineTo(407.33,333.33);
chocoears.lineTo(407.33,333.33);
chocoears.lineTo(403.67,329.67);
chocoears.lineTo(403.67,329.67);
chocoears.lineTo(403.67,329.67);
chocoears.lineTo(399.00,331.67);
chocoears.lineTo(399.00,331.67);
chocoears.lineTo(399.00,331.67);
chocoears.lineTo(396.33,329.33);
chocoears.lineTo(396.33,329.33);
chocoears.lineTo(396.33,329.33);
chocoears.lineTo(394.33,326.67);
chocoears.lineTo(394.33,326.67);
chocoears.lineTo(394.33,326.67);
chocoears.lineTo(386.67,326.33);
chocoears.lineTo(386.67,326.33);
chocoears.lineTo(386.67,326.33);
chocoears.lineTo(382.33,320.67);
chocoears.lineTo(382.33,320.67);
chocoears.lineTo(382.33,320.67);
chocoears.lineTo(378.00,322.00);
chocoears.lineTo(378.00,322.00);
chocoears.lineTo(378.00,322.00);
chocoears.lineTo(372.00,320.00);
chocoears.lineTo(372.00,320.00);
chocoears.lineTo(372.00,320.00);
chocoears.lineTo(373.33,318.00);
chocoears.lineTo(373.33,318.00);
chocoears.lineTo(373.33,318.00);
chocoears.lineTo(371.33,315.67);
chocoears.lineTo(371.33,315.67);
chocoears.lineTo(371.33,315.67);
chocoears.lineTo(365.33,316.00);
chocoears.lineTo(365.33,316.00);
chocoears.lineTo(365.33,316.00);
chocoears.lineTo(355.25,312.00);
chocoears.lineTo(355.25,312.00);
chocoears.lineTo(355.25,312.00);
chocoears.lineTo(361.00,310.88);
chocoears.lineTo(361.00,310.88);
chocoears.lineTo(361.00,310.88);
chocoears.lineTo(364.50,309.75);
chocoears.lineTo(364.50,309.75);
chocoears.lineTo(364.50,309.75);
chocoears.lineTo(367.75,307.50);
chocoears.lineTo(367.75,307.50);
chocoears.lineTo(367.75,307.50);
chocoears.lineTo(373.25,302.50);
chocoears.lineTo(373.25,302.50);
chocoears.lineTo(373.25,302.50);
chocoears.lineTo(379.13,296.13);
chocoears.lineTo(379.13,296.13);
chocoears.lineTo(379.13,296.13);
chocoears.lineTo(384.25,290.13);
chocoears.lineTo(384.25,290.13);
chocoears.lineTo(384.25,290.13);
chocoears.lineTo(389.25,283.88);
chocoears.lineTo(389.25,283.88);
chocoears.lineTo(389.25,283.88);
chocoears.lineTo(393.25,279.50);
chocoears.lineTo(393.25,279.50);
chocoears.lineTo(393.25,279.50);
chocoears.lineTo(396.63,275.50);
chocoears.lineTo(396.63,275.50);
chocoears.lineTo(396.63,275.50);
chocoears.lineTo(400.50,271.38);
chocoears.lineTo(400.50,271.38);
chocoears.lineTo(400.50,271.38);
chocoears.lineTo(406.25,266.75);
chocoears.lineTo(406.25,266.75);
chocoears.lineTo(406.25,266.75);
chocoears.lineTo(411.50,262.13);
chocoears.lineTo(411.50,262.13);
chocoears.lineTo(411.50,262.13);
chocoears.lineTo(414.88,259.75);
chocoears.lineTo(414.88,259.75);
chocoears.lineTo(414.88,259.75);
chocoears.lineTo(420.25,256.63);
chocoears.lineTo(420.25,256.63);
chocoears.lineTo(420.25,256.63);
chocoears.lineTo(424.63,253.88);
chocoears.lineTo(424.63,253.88);
chocoears.lineTo(424.63,253.88);
chocoears.lineTo(427.50,252.88);
chocoears.lineTo(427.50,252.88);
chocoears.lineTo(427.50,252.88);
chocoears.lineTo(431.13,251.50);
chocoears.lineTo(431.13,251.50);
chocoears.lineTo(431.13,251.50);
chocoears.lineTo(434.25,251.13);
chocoears.lineTo(434.25,251.13);
chocoears.lineTo(434.25,251.13);
chocoears.lineTo(437.63,251.00);
chocoears.lineTo(437.63,251.00);
chocoears.lineTo(437.63,251.00);
chocoears.lineTo(442.50,252.25);
chocoears.lineTo(442.50,252.25);
chocoears.lineTo(442.50,252.25);
chocoears.lineTo(445.50,253.75);
chocoears.lineTo(445.50,253.75);
chocoears.lineTo(445.50,253.75);
chocoears.lineTo(447.88,255.25);
chocoears.lineTo(447.88,255.25);
chocoears.lineTo(447.88,255.25);
chocoears.lineTo(450.50,258.25);
chocoears.lineTo(450.50,258.25);
chocoears.lineTo(450.50,258.25);
chocoears.lineTo(451.88,260.75);
chocoears.lineTo(451.88,260.75);
chocoears.lineTo(451.88,260.75);
chocoears.lineTo(453.38,264.13);
chocoears.lineTo(453.38,264.13);
chocoears.lineTo(453.38,264.13);
chocoears.lineTo(454.25,266.88);
chocoears.lineTo(454.25,266.88);
chocoears.lineTo(454.25,266.88);
chocoears.lineTo(455.50,271.13);
chocoears.lineTo(455.50,271.13);
chocoears.lineTo(455.50,271.13);
chocoears.lineTo(455.63,274.75);
chocoears.lineTo(455.63,274.75);
chocoears.lineTo(455.63,274.75);
chocoears.lineTo(456.75,276.50);
chocoears.lineTo(456.75,276.50);
chocoears.lineTo(456.75,276.50);
chocoears.lineTo(458.63,278.00);
chocoears.lineTo(458.63,278.00);
chocoears.lineTo(458.63,278.00);
chocoears.lineTo(460.00,278.88);
chocoears.lineTo(460.00,278.88);
chocoears.lineTo(460.00,278.88);
chocoears.lineTo(461.00,280.75);
chocoears.lineTo(461.00,280.75);
chocoears.lineTo(461.00,280.75);
chocoears.lineTo(462.75,281.00);
chocoears.lineTo(462.75,281.00);
chocoears.lineTo(462.75,281.00);
chocoears.lineTo(464.88,281.88);
chocoears.lineTo(464.88,281.88);
chocoears.lineTo(464.88,281.88);
chocoears.lineTo(467.38,283.00);
chocoears.lineTo(467.38,283.00);
chocoears.lineTo(467.38,283.00);
chocoears.lineTo(470.13,284.50);
chocoears.lineTo(470.13,284.50);
chocoears.lineTo(470.13,284.50);
chocoears.lineTo(472.00,286.13);
chocoears.lineTo(472.00,286.13);
chocoears.closePath();
g2.draw(chocoears);
Color milkChocolate = new Color(111,68,51);
g2.setColor(milkChocolate);
g2.fill(chocoears);

//Grass
Rectangle grass = new Rectangle(0,525,getWidth(),100);
Color lawnGreen = new Color(124,252,0);
g2.setColor(lawnGreen);
g2.fill(grass);

List<Arc2D> blades = new ArrayList<Arc2D>();
for (int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x += 10) {
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(x, 500, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(x - 5, 510, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));
    blades.add(new Arc2D.Double(x, 520, 10, 35, 105, 180, Arc2D.OPEN));

}
Color yellowGreen = new Color(107, 142, 35);
g2.setColor(yellowGreen);
for (Shape blade : blades) {
    g2.draw(blade);
}
Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(60,100,25,25);
g2.setColor(Color.RED);
g2.fill(circle);
Rectangle box = new Rectangle(150,100,20,80);
g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
g2.fill(box);


}   
}
```

Comment: I would clean up the code by putting the data into a file, perhaps a text file, and use the code for code, not for data. Then read in the data on program start, and draw your bunny.

Comment: I also would draw once to a BufferedImage, and then display the image in my `paintComponent(...)` method.

Comment: how can I do the first part? (.txt file)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do I would

1. create the Path2D objects outside of the paintComponent() method.
2. add each Path2D object to an ArrayList
3. in the paintComponent() method you can iterate through the ArrayList to paint each Path2D

Or another approach is to just have a method that:

1. creates each Path2D object when the class is created
2. then you paint the Path2D object to a `BufferedImage`
3. now that you have a BufferedImage you can create an ImageIcon and Just use a JLabel in you app and you don't need the custom panel.

Comment: @user3394902, you learn by trying. The first approach is the easiest. So you start by moving the code that builds the Path2D objects to a separate method that you execute in the constructor of you class. Ass you create each Path2D object you add it to an ArrayList. Then in the paintComponent() method all you need is a couple of lines of code to iterate through the ArrayList and paint each Path2D object.

Comment: See the `DrawOnComponent` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). It is very similar to what you are doing except it paint ColoredRectangles instead of Path2D objects.

Comment: I think I'm grasping the idea of this but I might need some help as I've tried to create an object for something completely different somewhat unsuccessfully. But, I'll try to translate it into that and post the code if I get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Heres 2 options I would consider for cleaning up the pathing.

1. Use SVG, one library I know is Batik found at: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/
2. Once I did a project where the paths I needed would be created in photoshop then exported to Illustrator. The file format was each action was line delineated, each line was space delineated and consisted of a set of points with the last entry the command name. Here was a sample input.

   `10 10 m
    15 15 l
    10 10 12 12 v`

As you can see you just read the file, create your path and do an if test for the last letter on the line and use the appropriate command with for the points. Of course you can make up your own format or procedures but it sure was nice using photoshop for me :)

Comment: I alreadu use batik to get the coordinates. I used gimp to create the path but it just needs to be able to run on any computer